# Point to an XML file in android

Tags: android, xml

Hello i'm new to android and in my application i want to get some data from an XML file..but it gives an error saying file not found error..Can anyone tell me how to correctly ponit to a file in android.Thanx in advance.

Exception:-

09-18 12:24:19.889: WARN/System.err(2550): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /res/xml/persons.xml (No such file or directory)

Comment: try passing `/xml/persons.xml` to File().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content stored within the /res/ folder is not within the regular filesystem. You need to access it from the resources. Call `getResources` from your activity, and you can see the functions there to operate on resources. Depending on what are you calling, there may already be an overload that takes a resource id already. Note that it might make more sense to move your xml to the /raw/ folder instead of /xml/.

You can open an InputStream to your resource file like this:

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.persons);
```

'context' would generaly be your activity.